# Multiple carousels affecting each other in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have multiple carousels on web page. When I click on the thumbnails at the bottom of the page it opens up an individual pop-up carousel for each section. But when I click on them they seem to be updating the carousel at the top. They insert into the carousel at the top. How are the carousels at the bottom effecting the one at the top?

Here's the HTML code.

```
<div class="container">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="assets/example/test.jpg">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h2>1</h2>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="assets/example/test.jpg">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h2>2</h2>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="assets/example/test.jpg">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h2>3</h2>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>       
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>  
</div>
</div>
<!-- /.carousel -->


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Bootstrap 3 lightbox hidden gallery using modal</h1>
        <hr>

    <div class="row">

                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a title="Image 1" href="#"> 
                        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" id="image-1" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x350/ccc/969696&amp;text=0xD10x810xD00xB50xD10x800xD10x8B0xD00xB9">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a title="Image 2" href="#"> 
                        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" id="image-2" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x350/2255EE/969696&amp;text=0xD10x810xD00xB80xD00xBD0xD00xB80xD00xB9">
                    </a>

                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a title="Image 3" href="#"> 
                        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" id="image-3" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x350/449955/FFF&amp;text=0xD00xB70xD00xB50xD00xBB0xD00xB50xD00xBD0xD10x8B0xD00xB9">
                    </a>
                </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hidden" id="img-repo">

    <!-- #image-1 -->
    <div class="item" id="image-1">
        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 11" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x350/ccc/969696">
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="image-1">
        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 12" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/ccc/969696">
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="image-1">
        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 13" src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/ccc/969696">
    </div>

    <!-- #image-2 -->
    <div class="item" id="image-2">
        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 21" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x350/2255EE/969696">
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="image-2">
        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 21" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/2255EE/969696">
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="image-2">
        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 23" src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/2255EE/969696">
    </div>   

    <!-- #image-3-->
    <div class="item" id="image-3">
        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 31" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x350/449955/FFF">
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="image-3">
        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 32" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/449955/FFF">
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="image-3">
        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 33" src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/449955/FFF">
    </div>        

</div>

  <div class="modal" id="modal-gallery" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="modal-carousel" class="carousel">

              <div class="carousel-inner">           
              </div>

              <a class="carousel-control left" href="#mycarousel2" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
              <a class="carousel-control right" href="#mycarousel2" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type='text/javascript' src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- JavaScript jQuery code from Bootply.com editor  -->
  <script type='text/javascript'>


    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.carousel').each(function(){

          $(this).carousel({interval: 3000});

          /* change modal title when slide changes */
          $("#mycarousel2").on("slid.bs.carousel", function () {
              $(".modal-title").html($(this).find(".active img").attr("title"));
      })

      /* when clicking a thumbnail */
      $(".row .thumbnail").click(function(){
          var content = $(".carousel-inner");
          var title = $(".modal-title");

          content.empty();  
          title.empty();

          var id = this.id;  
          var repo = $("#img-repo .item");
          var repoCopy = repo.filter("#" + id).clone();
          var active = repoCopy.first();

          active.addClass("active");
          title.html(active.find("img").attr("title"));
          content.append(repoCopy);

          // show the modal
          $("#modal-gallery").modal("show");
      });
  });
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tkkfxr34/

Comment: A JSFiddle or something similar would be helpful